# Multiple ajax requests giving unauthorized 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using rails app. Many times I receive for ajax requests the status "401" with response "Unauthorized". Sometimes on refresh the page (with F5) it is working, Some times only one request is receiving 401 status

> Completed 401 Unauthorized

I saw [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/many-time-401-unauthorized-on-ajax-requests) post. Its the exact same issue I am getting but did not find any solution for it.

I am using rails 4.2.1. Do not know how to resolve the issue?

Comment: do you control the API? have you looked at the server logs on why it is returning 401?

Comment: When making simultaneous XHR requests, session data may be lost due to concurrent requests updating the session at the same time